# PyOpenGL 3D Snake Game' can't seem to find a way to increment the snake segments

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

i have recently started working with the pyopengl library and to test my knowledge i have decided to make a game.
I have been having some issues with finishing the last part of the game tho, adding segments to the snake/making them follow you, down below you can find the source code of the game, there is a multilined comment, that's what i've tried doing and it didn't work, would appreciate any help if possible.

```
import random

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


pygame.init()

edges = (
    (0, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4)
)

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
)

colors = (
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1)
)

def Cube(InputX, InputY, InputZ, color):
    verticies = (
        (InputX + 1, InputY + -1, InputZ + -1),
        (InputX + 1, InputY + 1, InputZ + -1),
        (InputX + -1, InputY + 1, InputZ + -1),
        (InputX + -1, InputY + -1, InputZ + -1),
        (InputX + 1, InputY + -1, InputZ + 1),
        (InputX + 1, InputY + 1, InputZ + 1),
        (InputX + -1, InputY + -1, InputZ + 1),
        (InputX + -1, InputY + 1, InputZ + 1)
    )
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        x = 0
        for vortex in surface:
            x += 1
            glColor3fv(colors[color])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vortex])
    glEnd()


    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glColor3fv(colors[10])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()


headx = 0
heady = 0
RandX = random.randint(0, 28/2)  * 2
RandY = random.randint(0, 28/2) * 2


grid = [[0] * 10 for x in range(9)]


display = (750, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

gluPerspective(120, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

#First image to display
glTranslatef(-13, -13, -10)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
Cubes = [[Cube(2*x,2*y, -5, 9) for x in range(15)] for y in range(15)]#Grid
Cube(headx, heady, -5, 1)
Cube(RandX, RandY, -5, 6)
pygame.display.flip()


dir = (0, 0)
MOVEEVENT, t = pygame.USEREVENT+1, 1
pygame.time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT, t)
Score = 0
Time = -1000

TailPos = [[3,3], [2,3]]


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]: dir = (0, -1)
    if keys[pygame.K_a]: dir = (-1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: dir = (0, 1)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]: dir = (1, 0)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOVEEVENT:  # is called every 't' milliseconds
            if(dir == (0, -1)):
                heady += 2
            elif (dir == (-1, 0)):
                headx -= 2
            elif (dir == (0, 1)):
                heady -= 2
            elif (dir == (1, 0)):
                headx += 2



        if (headx >= 30): # checking if the snake is going out of bounds
            headx = 0
        elif (headx <= -1):
            headx = 28
        elif (heady >= 30):
            heady = 0
        elif (heady <= -1):
            heady = 28

        if((headx == RandX) and (heady == RandY)):
            RandX, RandY = random.randint(0, 28/2) * 2, random.randint(0, 28/2) * 2
            Score += 10
            #if(Time > 10):
            #    Time -= 10
            #    print(Time)
        '''for i in range(len(TailPos) - 1, 0, -1):
            TailPos[i][0] = TailPos[i - 1][0];
            TailPos[i][1] = TailPos[i - 1][1];
            for j in range(len(TailPos)-1):
                Cube(TailPos[i][j], TailPos[i][j], -5, 1)  # Snake
        for x in range(len(TailPos)):
            for segment in TailPos:
                for part in segment:
                    Cube(part,part, -5, 1)'''

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cubes = [[Cube(2*x,2*y, -5, 9) for x in range(15)] for y in range(15)]#Grid



        Cube(RandX, RandY, -5, 6)#Fruit
        Cube(headx, heady, -5, 1)  # Snake

        pygame.time.wait(Time)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: you need either dynamic or static list. For the latter you need to preallocate the list to max size of your snake and add some variable that tells you how much of the list items are valid ... Also combining this with ring buffer will ease up the movement simulation quite a lot (from `O(n)` to `O(1)`).

Comment: like so ? d = collections.deque(maxlen=10)

Comment: @Spektre forgot to mention you

Comment: I do not code in python so I am not sure In C++ like languages it is something like `float point[max][2]={(0.0,0.0),1.0,0.0}; int points=2;` where `point[i][2]` is point of snake and `points` is how many of them are valid. When you add new point set `point[points][2]` with the coordinates and increment `points` but in python you should have some list template natively.